# Is there a way to use a particle system on a mesh with a re-mesh modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, particles

Recently I ran into an issue with the *Re-mesh* modifier. I tried to use a particle system with a mesh with a *Re-mesh* modifier, and the results do not render. I can get them to preview in the view-port, but they are not visible in the rendered image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED: I have discovered a solution to the issue. Move the particle system up the modifier stack until it is above the *Re-mesh* modifier.

[image]

Now particles render normally. One thing you must realize, is that particle orientation will be based off of the original mesh, not the modified mesh.